# Bash command to flatten nested dicrectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

I have a directory structure like this

```
a/1/01.jpg
b/2/01.jpg
c/3/01.jpg
```

I want to make it into a structure like this

```
a1/01.jpg
b2/01.jpg
c3/01.jpg
```

So far I have a bash command that looks like this

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d -execdir bash -c 'mv -i \"$1\" ./\"${1//\/\[/_[}\"' bash {} \;
```

However the command failed with these statements

```
mv: cannot stat '"./3"': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '"./2"': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '"./1"': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing that by using plain `bash` would be easier:

```
#!/bin/bash

for src in */*/; do
    dst=${src/\/}
    echo mkdir "$dst"
    echo mv "$src"* "$dst"
done
```

Remove both `echo`s if the output looks fine.

Or, a more efficient version:

```
for src in */*/; do
    mv "$src" "${src/\/}"
done
```

but this version won't work properly when the destination directory (`a1`, `b2`, `c3`, etc.) already exists.

Comment: @jhnc Retaining the last `/` in `dst` is better. Assume that an ordinary file named `a1` exists. Then `mkdir "$dst"` will fail: In case of `dst=${src//\/}`, the file `a1` will be overwritten (if there is exactly one file in the directory `a/1/`. But it won't be, in case of `dst=${src/\/}`, because `mv "$src"* "$dst"` will fail.

Comment: @jhnc `mv "$src" "$dst"` would result in `a1/1/01.jpg`, `b2/2/01.jpg`, `c3/3/01.jpg`. The OP wants `a1/01.jpg`, `b2/01.jpg`, `c3/01.jpg`. Hence `mv "$src"* "$dst"`

Comment: @jhnc I've already tried before posting the comment and it works exactly as stated in the comment. `mkdir` is required to create the directories `a1`, `b2`, `c3` (if they don't already exist).

Comment: @jhnc If the directory `c/` exists before the `mv a/b/ c/` command then it will give you `c/b/f`

Comment: @jhnc And yes, this is to handle merging into possibly already existing directories. In this case, `mkdir "$dst"` will fail but I think this is harmless.

Answer (score 0):

All operations need to be performed on the leaf directories. These are identified by having two links which you can find with:

```
$ find -type d -links 2
```

Once you have these directories, you only have to rename the directory

```
$ find -type d -links 2 -exec sh -c 'd1={};d2="${d1#./}"; [ "$d2" = "${d2//\//}" ] ||  mv -v "$d1" "${d2//\//}"' \;
```

Find will complain a bit as you moved a directory away that it was traversing, but this should do it.

If you have a pure structure, i.e. files only appear in leaf-directories, this should do it. All you need to do now is delete the empty directories:

```
$ find -type d -empty -delete
```

Be aware, however, that if a leaf directory was already empty, the latter will remove it.